# Eager evaluation of RDD when AQE is enabled

Tags: apache-spark

Jobs that have `.rdd` calls get executed 2x.

We have a few spark scala jobs that are currently running in production. Most jobs typically use Dataset, Dataframes. There is a small code in our custom library code, that makes rdd calls example to check if the dataframe is empty:
`df.rdd.getNumPartitions == 0`

When I enable aqe for these jobs, this `.rdd` is converted into a separate job of it's own and the entire job is executed 2x, taking 2x more time. This does not happen when AQE is disabled. Why does this happen and what is the best way to fix the issue?